# What is the relationship between the common concept of "model" and "model" as used in Model Theory?

Tags: model-theory, philosophy

To my understanding, a *model* in Model Theory is an interpretation (in a form of a set or other algebraic structures) for a certain sentence S which makes S true.

In everyday language, and also in other branches of science (physics, computer science, biology, ...), *model* means a formal language used to give an abstract description of phenomena, highlighting only the details we care about for the current analysis.

So, how do these two concepts relate to each other? Since we use the same word, I figured that there may be a connection which could make my understanding of these concepts deeper. In particular, I wonder why we use the world "model" in the "common sense" instead of language, abstract language, formalism, etc.

Comment: "highlighting only the details we care about" - and the details we care about are precsely the truth and falsehood of sentences

Comment: See [Model Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/) and [Models in Science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/models-science/).

Comment: See laso the post [What motivated the choice of the word “model” in model theory?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/what-motivated-the-choice-of-the-word-model-in-model-theory)